# Interpret reuslts of PLS regression coefficients

Tags: python, regression-coefficients, scikit-learn, partial-least-squares

I have performed PLS regression using `sklearn` library (python 2.7) over three types of soil (PLS model per soil type) and I plotted the regression coefficients, but in the most right plot in the picture, the bars seem a bit bizarre, where one band is positive and the next is negative. Does it mean something? or this is a valid result?
(the black curve is an average spectrum, you can ignore it)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by PLS model per soil type?

Comment: It means that I have 3 datasets (one per soil type), each dataset has X and y. For each dataset I've generated a PLS model

Comment: Would you care to tell us what your y variable is, what your X are (derivative of mid-IR spectra from?), how many samples are in your data and how many latent variables you use and how you decided that number?

Comment: I'm not sure how this will help.. but the y is a percentage of a contaminant (from 0 to 10%), the spectrum (X) is continuum removal values, there are about 2000 samples, LV=7 based on RMSE

Comment: Hmm. So X ≈ Reflectance, just you don't have the true $I_0$ and therefore estimate it by the convex hull of the sample spectra, right? I'm asking also because while I've seen this in the VIS and NIR spectral ranges, I've never seen it in the mid-IR. In any case, from a spectroscopic point of view, I'd expect - log R (which is closely related to absorbance) rather than R itself to be linear with concentration, so you may need far fewer latent variables for prediction if you convert X. How did you obtain RMSE? By cross validation?

Answer (score 3):

(This answer for now is preliminary, pending OP's explanation what exactly the data is)

Well acquired spectra with good spectroscopic resolution are typically expected to be smooth continuous functions of the wavelength.
Thus, doing a regression for a given analyte, one usually* expects that one wavelength channel is almost as good as its neighbour wavelength channel for predicting, and in fact that their coefficients should be almost the same. In other words, we expect high correlation between neighboring wavelength channels/variates (that's the smooth spectrum we have) and also high correlation between neighbour coefficients: the coefficient pattern is expected to be smooth and continuous as well.

Coefficient patterns that are visibly noisy, i.e. are (randomly) fluctuating between positive and negative from one channel/variate/wavelength to the next mean that the model tries to pick tiny differences between neighboring wavelength channels. Typcially, this is a sign of overfitting. An accompanying symptom is usually that the absolute values of the coefficients get very large.

From the left to the right I'd get more and more suspicious of overfitting, though for the vibrational spectra I work with I'd say that already the leftmost model would need some closer inspection wrt. overfitting.

Things to do:

- Check stability of your PLS models. For PLS, that can easily be done directly as the coefficients $\mathbf Y_c = \mathbf X_c \mathbf B$ (not the loadings!) e.g. of the surrogate models trained during cross validation should be equal or at least very similar.
- Compare quality of spectra (noise level), number of available spectra and "ease" of the regression problem (is the analyte/property in question plainly visible in the spectra) with the chosen number of latent variables.
  Reducing the number of latent variables corresponds to stronger regularization and thus to less overfitting (classical bias-variance tradeoff).
- PLS gives a regularization and as such already helps a lot stabilizing the regression. However, it cannot work miracles. It may help to trade in some spectral resolution in order to gain signal-to-noise ratio for your spectra. This can be done in a way that also lowers the number of wavelength channels/variates, which in turn  helps the PLS estimation additionally due to lower dimensionality.

---

* there are some exceptions, notably, if you are after some analyte with very narrow signal that is covered only by a single wavelength channel. But this would correspond to a coefficient pattern where a single channel sticks out, not the noisy pattern you have in figure 3.

Or, of course if the spectra are acquired at low resolution, so neighboring wavelength channels are not (highly) correlated.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I did what you suggested and ran the PLS model 10 times with stratified k-fold (k=10) and compared the beta coefficients for each run. What I've noticed is that the variation is lower for bands with a high coefficient and vice versa. It means that if a specific band got beta =50 (relatively high) in the first run, then it will get also higher coefficients (~50) in the next runs, but if a specific band received relatively low beta (e.g., 7), then in the next runs it can get 0.5 or even 19. So I can trust the hight beta bands. Would you agree?

Comment: @user88484: can you upload a plot of the results? However, once you have the PLS model, you cannot decide to exclude certain coefficients and keep others. What you can do, though, is to have a look at the loadings: as soon as they get noisy (in some regions), you have too many.

Comment: Great explanation! I have a question regarding the 3rd option to mitigate the over-fitting: could you elaborate more on what you mean by "trade in some spectral resolution"? Is this meaning I should smooth the spectra?

Comment: @Vickyyy: yes, in a way it is a smoothing operation. But not all smoothing operations are the same in this respect: consider Savitzky-Golay-smoothing vs. binning of neighbour spectral channels. SG will give you lower noise on the same number of spectral channels. But it will also "smear out" information:  in fact, your spectra have lower spectral resolution afterwards. But the number of data points is the same. Thus, you have data now that is oversampled in the spectral dimension. This means that the PLS models has more coefficients than necessary to describe the spectra...

Comment: If you bin, not only is the SNR increased, but the numer of data points/measurement channels is also reduced: thus the PLS has less noisy data and *in addition* needs to estimate fewer coefficients. I.e. you have a two-fold gain for the stability of your model. IMHO: if you have to smooth your spectra, there is no point in keeping them oversamples in terms of no. of data points. 
Note that there's a lot of smoothing possibilities besides binning that do such a downsampling that both reduces no of data points and increases SNR. (E.g. for FT-spectra, you may do this during the FT)

Comment: @cbeleites Thanks for the reply! Please point out if I am wrong, so binning is actually a better way than using other naive smoothing techniques. Sorry I am really new to this, so could you explain a little more about "binning of neighbour spectral channels"? How exactly does this work, does it mean by choosing a bandwidth and replace the value in that wavelength band with the average? (replacing the spectra with it's corresponding histogram). If that's true, how should I determine the band width? Is there any paper/notes that I can refer to? Thanks again!

Comment: @Vickyyy: Binning: you take every n wavelength in the spectrum and replace them by sum (or average) and do the same with the wavelength, yes. Yes, that's similar to calculating a histogram, but the spectra themselves are similar to that already: each data point is the sum of all photons (ions for MS) that fall into the spectral range belonging to that data "point". There are many other smoothing functions that also provide both an interpolation to other (fewer) data points/channels. Just the widely used SG smoothing doesn't.

Comment: @cbeleites Hi thanks for the reply! I have looked over some papers and tutorials, and it seems that lots of them use SG as the preprocessing step. I am not sure if this is a common mistake (I understand your rational and I agree with that) or it depends on the context?

Comment: @Vickyyy: Both. SG is a *very* common smoothing procedure - that's why I explicitly mentioned that in the context of smoothing in order to stabilize unstable models it is not optimal as it doesn't do smoothing and downsampling (you could construct filters that are similar to SG and do this - but they wouldn't be called SG any more). And it is wasefully applied this way, yes. OTOH: SG does smoothing and differentiation simultaneously: so if that's what you're looking for SG is fine (and if you consider derivatives, you typically don't want to loose spectral resolution).

Answer (score 0):

PLS, like many of the linear models, can get very confused when there is a high degree of correlation between features. You might be seeing an artifact of that here.
The typical remedy is to remove correlated features.

EDIT: removed mention of PCA

Comment: I'm not sure I got your EDIT comment. What do you mean by "removed mention of PCA"?

Comment: Well, as PLS is typically used in order to take care (by regularization) of a data set with multi-collinearity, some further explanation seems to be needed here.